# Token based authentication and authorization with angular and yii2 using oAuth2 protocol(HttpBearerAuth)

Tags: angularjs, api, authorization, yii2, token

I am trying to perform login using token based authentication and authorization but stuck at authorization on action dashboard in ApiController because in my main config file, I have set :

```
'enableSession' => false,
```

and in ApiController, I have :

```
public function actionDashboard()
    {
        $response = [
            'username' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
            'access_token' => Yii::$app->user->identity->getAuthKey(),
        ];
        return $response;
    }
```

I am unable to perform authorization process using token properly. Here is my complete code.

main-local.php :

```
<?php
use \yii\web\Request;

$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

$config = [
    'language' => 'en-US',
    'name'=>'Lead Battery Recycling',
     'components' => [
         'user' => [
             'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    'enableSession' => false,
    'loginUrl' => null,

            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_frontendUser', // unique for backend
                'path'=>'/gravita_lbp/frontend/web'  // correct path for the backend app.
            ]
        ],
         'session' => [
            'name' => 'PHPFRONTSESSID',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp',
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '7ZO7uJfychV7ozQOPnfQGS6zdXLz9Lx0',
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'parsers' => [
                 'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'api'],
            ],
        ],
           'urlManagerBackEnd' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '/gravita_lbp/backend/web/',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
        'allowActions' => [
           'site/*',
            'api/login',
            'api/dashboard' // add or remove allowed actions to this list
        ]
    ],


];
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

ApiController.php :

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\filters\ContentNegotiator;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
/**
 * Site controller
 */
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            'only' => ['dashboard'],
        ];
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ];
        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['dashboard'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['dashboard'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {    

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '') && $model->login()) {

            return ['access_token' => Yii::$app->user->identity->getAuthKey()];
        } else {
            $model->validate();
            return $model;
        }

    }
    public function actionDashboard()
    {

        $response = [
            'username' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username,
            'access_token' => Yii::$app->user->identity->getAuthKey(),
        ];
        return $response;
    }
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '') && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                $response = [
                    'flash' => [
                        'class' => 'success',
                        'message' => 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.',
                    ]
                ];
            } else {
                $response = [
                    'flash' => [
                        'class' => 'error',
                        'message' => 'There was an error sending email.',
                    ]
                ];
            }
            return $response;
        } else {
            $model->validate();
            return $model;
        }
    }
}
```

controller.js :

```
'use strict';

var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

controllers.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$location', '$window',
    function ($scope, $location, $window) {
        $scope.loggedIn = function() {
            return Boolean($window.sessionStorage.access_token);
        };

        $scope.logout = function () {
            delete $window.sessionStorage.access_token;
            $location.path('/login').replace();
        };
    }
]);

controllers.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window',
    function($scope, $http, $window) {
        $scope.captchaUrl = 'site/captcha';
        $scope.contact = function () {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.error = {};
            $http.post('api/contact', $scope.contactModel).success(
                function (data) {
                    $scope.contactModel = {};
                    $scope.flash = data.flash;
                    $window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    $scope.submitted = false;
                    $scope.captchaUrl = 'site/captcha' + '?' + new Date().getTime();
            }).error(
                function (data) {
                    angular.forEach(data, function (error) {
                        $scope.error[error.field] = error.message;
                    });
                }
            );
        };

        $scope.refreshCaptcha = function() {
            $http.get('site/captcha?refresh=1').success(function(data) {
                $scope.captchaUrl = data.url;
            });
        };
    }]);

controllers.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/lbp/api/dashboard').success(function (data) {
           $scope.dashboard = data;
        })
    }
]);

controllers.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $location) {
        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.error = {};
            $http.post('/lbp/api/login', $scope.userModel).success(
                function (data) {
                    $window.sessionStorage.access_token = data.access_token;
                    $location.path('/dashboard').replace();
            }).error(
                function (data) {
                    angular.forEach(data, function (error) {
                        $scope.error[error.field] = error.message;
                    });
                }
            );
        };
    }
]);
```

Please suggest me a solution for this, I just want to do this by using rest API only.

Answer (score 3):

I am late in post but may be helpful for future reader.

You need to send your access_token in every request. Suppose, create simple factory called auth.js

```
app.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      if ($window.sessionStorage.access_token) {
        //HttpBearerAuth
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' +     $window.sessionStorage.access_token;
      }
      return config;
    },
  }
});
```

and add

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

inside your angular.module which helps you to add

```
Authorization:Bearer your_access_token
```

in request header.And used by your Yii controller behavior to authenticate your user.

Answer (score 1):

Since RESTful API is stateless, 
so you should keep sessions set to false. 
Then, you need not to mix two separate issues;

- developer authentication
- end-user authentication

Normally, you shall authenticate developers first 
before allowing them to use the API either using 
Basic Credentials or Bearer Tokens.
Afterwards, you shall expose your resources as endpoints 
which a developer can query. That's you may consider breaking 
the dashboard down to components that could be queried separately.